# YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI getting issue in Android.?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting issue like this

> W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay:acqm@6b45523 helper:Lazy@8cb1a20 view:null status: ....... {...}

```
> W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{d1a0545 VFED.V... .F...... 0,0-1080,1554 #7f0e007b app:id/details_recyclerview}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: -48, right: 0, bottom: 1002 (these should all be positive).
```

implemented in Recycleview

**Issue**: first time when user entered screen it's working fine, when user scroll up and down video playing in background but black screen showing in top of the video

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/header_navigation" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/details_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_color"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

my recycle item.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_video_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/article_details_background"
    android:visibility="visible"></com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_video_player"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/artical_image_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_details_background_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/article_details_background"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/article_view_details"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>             
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/161

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the error message you are not allowed to overlay any View to a YouTubePlayer, have you tried pausing the player when it goes off screen?

In case you're interested, I have been building a library to avoid this kind of issues, [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player). This will give you a lot more freedom on what you can do with the player.